# Insert terminal output to compilation or record time needed

Tags: compiling

For some reason my document takes very long to compile, and I would like to narrow down why this happens. Finding the bottleneck would be greatly eased if I could time how long individual sections in the code take to compile.

The first and obvious question is: **(1) Is there a 'profiler' package that returns how long parts of my documents take to compile?**
Such a package should record, for example, how long individual Ti *k* Z pictures take to compile.

If this should not be an option, I have a second question: **(2) Is it possible to output statements into the terminal?**
If there was something like a command `"shellout(print "Now compiling PGF Plot of weather data...")`, that would print a statement in the terminal among all those LaTeX warnings I get, I could at least stop the time myself.

Comment: I have no answer for (1). About (2), you can add the line `\typeout{Now compiling PGF Plot of weather data...}` in the right point in your document. In this way that line will be printed in the `.log` file and you should be able to see it in the terminal.

Comment: you can use `\message` to output things on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a line `\typeout{START TRACING}\tracingmacros1` at the start of the sub-part of interest in the `latex` document, and then `\typeout{STOP TRACING}\tracingmacros0`at the end of the stuff. This will sometimes considerably slow down the compilation, but once it is done, go to the `log` file and ask your editor to report the number of lines from `START TRACING` to `STOP TRACING`. This line count will give a rough idea of the time taken up by that part of the source. But you need to repeat for another part to compare.

You could also do this simultaneously for various sub-regions of the source, and then compare the line counts.